# Closing an SWF File using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file-io

How do I close an SWF file using AS3? I want to include the close in an event listener, so when the user clicks a button the application will close. I tried:

```
fscommand("quit");
```

which doesn't work.

I simply want to unload an SWF running from an FLA file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well that's not that easy. You can't unload the movie clip from within itself. This is only possible through `Loader.unloadAndStop()` meaning you have to load the swf from another swf.

The other option is to create a JavaScript that you can call from the swf, to remove the swf file reference from the page.

Answer (score 1):

When I faced the same situation, I designed externally loaded swf smaller than root scene. Placed a close button at root scene to unload the swf. by setting visibility of close button, I managed it.

//loading command

```
fl_ProLoader = new ProLoader();    
fl_ProLoader.load(new
URLRequest("OrgChart.swf"));    
addChild(fl_ProLoader);
```

//unloading command

```
fl_ProLoader.unload();    
removeChild(fl_ProLoader);    
fl_ProLoader = null;
```